# No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo '{0}' en 'string'

Tags: c#

Necesito retornar los valores de mi clase desde mi método pero tengo el siguiente mensaje: No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo "MiClase" a string.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public string CargadRQ(RequerimientoModelo m)
{
    try
    {
        string resultado = REST.RestWebService(strUrl + "/empresaRQ/" + m.CodEmpr + "/tipoRQ/" + m.TipoDocu + "/nuRQ/" + m.NuDocu + "", VariableGlobal.UsuaWS, VariableGlobal.PassWS, "GET", "");
        var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        serializer.RegisterConverters(new[] { new Utilitarios.DynamicJsonConverter() });
        serializer.MaxJsonLength = 900000000;

        dynamic listado = serializer.Deserialize(resultado, typeof(object));

        m.TipoDocu = listado[0]["TI_REQI"].ToString();
        m.NuDocu = listado[0]["NU_REQI"].ToString();
        m.NuSeriReqt = listado[0]["SERI_RQ"].ToString();
        m.UltiCorr = listado[0]["CORR_RQ"].ToString();

        return m;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: El valor de retorno del método es `string`. Cambialo a `RequerimientoModelo`

Comment: Adicionalmente tu `try-catch` no hace nada. Quítalo o maneja apropiadamente la excepción

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda me funcionó.

Comment: Si la respuesta te sirvió puedes marcarla como aceptada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El valor de retorno de tu método es de tipo `string`. Debes cambiarlo a `RequerimientoModelo`

```
public RequerimientoModelo CargadRQ(RequerimientoModelo m)
{
    // ...
    return m;
}
```